# Split string by character starting from the end of the string c++

Tags: c++, split

I'm trying to create some folders from a string file name with full path.

```
    string str = "c:/temp/tmp/test.txt";
    File_data data;
```

For this to work, I need to parse the string and remove the name of the file. What I would like to do is split the string from the back so that I can remove the file name from the created directory names.

Below is what I have so far. I split the string by "/" and then reform it, except for the last element of the array.

```
    char strArray[1000];
    strncpy(strArray, str, sizeof(strArray));
    char* objectArray[100] = {0};
    unsigned int index = 0;
    unsigned int secondIndex = 0;

    objectArray[index] = strtok(strArray, "/");
    while(objectArray[index] != 0)
    {
      ++index;
      objectArray[index] = strtok(0, "/");
    }

    while(objectArray[secondIndex] != 0)
    {
        if ((secondIndex - 1) != index)
        {
            data.name += objectArray[secondIndex];
            data.name += "/";
        }
        ++secondIndex;
    }
```

While the above code technically works, I still need to empty `data.name` before starting. I'm hoping that there is a simpler way to do all of this so that I can just remove the file name from the string and create a directory structure from the rest.

Comment: You should use a [`std:string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).  Then you could use functions like [`find_last_of()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_of)

Comment: use the find_last_of function in std::string , and substring an index after the return position of the last slash

Comment: You claim that the code works, but really, if `str` is a `std::string` object that `strncpy` call will cause a compiler error.

Comment: Don't use `strncpy` until you've read **and understood** its documentation. This code uses it in an attempt to avoid a buffer overflow, but it replaces buffer overflow with an unterminated string, which is just as bad.

Comment: Also, for handling paths and filesystem related things, you might want to look into [the Boost Filesystem library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) which have a very nice [`path` class](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#class-path).

Comment: And if you really want to use the C-style library functions, the one you're looking for is `strrchr()` which will find the last occurrence of a character.

Comment: Hey all I just want to add NathanOliver had it right I converted my string to std:string and using the example rtbaldwin gave bellow created the results I needed. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the substr and find functions from string. Substr takes position and length and returns the substring. Find takes a char or string value to check for and returns the iterator to the instance (first of and last of find the first and last instance respectively ).

In code do something like this:

```
auto pos = path.find_last_of ('/');
if (pos != string::npos) {
    directory = path.substr (0,pos);
    file = path.substr (pos);
}
```

Doing this on phone so apologize for ugly answer! :P